# #include "header_file.hpp" error. Task is to integrate iceoryx in C++ project

Tags: c++, linux, qt, makefile, include

I installed **iceoryx** from [git repository](https://github.com/eclipse-iceoryx/iceoryx) in my linux system following the procedure as described.
I am taking code snippets from example code given in iceoryx repository as I want to use iceoryx in my C++ project.
When I use the example code in my C++ project the `#include "iceoryx_hoofs/posix_wrapper/signal_watcher.hpp"` lines are showing an error: `no such file or directory`

```
#include "iceoryx_hoofs/posix_wrapper/signal_watcher.hpp"
#include "iceoryx_posh/popo/untyped_publisher.hpp"
#include "iceoryx_posh/runtime/posh_runtime.hpp"
```

I tried including the static path of these headers.

```
#include "/usr/local/includes/iceoryx/v2.90.0/iceoryx_hoofs/posix_wrapper/signal_watcher.hpp"
```

The same error message pops up.  `no such file or directory`

The make file also has the following lines

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/local/include
```

The `/usr/local/include` contains the iceoryx folder where the required header files are located after installation.

compile output

```
This is the compailer output.'../middleware/publisher_gpsdata.cpp:3:10: fatal error: iceoryx_hoofs/posix_wrapper/signal_watcher.hpp: No such file or directory
3 | #include "iceoryx_hoofs/posix_wrapper/signal_watcher.hpp"
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated. 
make: *** [Makefile:1258: publisher_gpsdata.o] Error 1
11:15:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project middleware (kit: Desktop Qt 5.15.2 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

The problem is, I have no experience of using a complete software downloaded from git and used it to develop a new project.
Tell me what is wrong and the steps required to include these headers in my C++ project. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: The important information is not present here.  Please cut and paste the complete, exact errors you're getting, and also the compiler invocation that  make invokes that causes those errors, with proper formatting.  You don't have to include all the errors, if there are lots of them, but include at least the first few and last few error lines.

Comment: I have updated the question with compile output

Comment: **Read the documentation of your C++ compiler**, probably [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). Notably read about [the C preprocessor *GNU cpp*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) and the documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). If using Qt, read [its documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/)

Answer (score 1):

You still didn't show us the most important thing: the compiler invocation (the compile command line that make printed).  You also didn't show us enough of your makefile to infer what it might look like.  If you've added `@` to the beginning of your compile lines so that make doesn't print them, well, that's bad.  Remove that so you can see what make is actually doing.

All we can give you is generalities.  If you have a line like:

```
#include "iceoryx_hoofs/posix_wrapper/signal_watcher.hpp"
```

then the compiler will append that path to each of the built-in locations it looks for, plus each of the `-I` options on the command line, to search for the file.

You say that the full path to that file is:

```
/usr/local/includes/iceoryx/v2.90.0/iceoryx_hoofs/posix_wrapper/signal_watcher.hpp
```

That means that on your compile line, you need to have the path:

```
-I/usr/local/includes/iceoryx/v2.90.0
```

so that when the path in the `#include` is appended to it, you'll find the right file.

Note, this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/local/include
```

is a bad idea.  You don't say how you USE these variables (again, you don't show your compile line or the part of your makefile that uses these) but it's not a good idea to use a shell variable like `$PWD`.  Not all shells set this variable, and not all the time.

You can either invoke `pwd`:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$(pwd)/../../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$(pwd)/../../../../../usr/local/include
```

or use make's `CURDIR` variable:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $(CURDIR)/../../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $(CURDIR)/../../../../../usr/local/include
```

but this is not enough since you're missing the `v2.90.0` directory.

Anyway, with the limited information you provided that's about all we can do to help.

Comment: On Linux, [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) could be useful

Answer (score 0):

The [iceoryx template GitHub repository](https://github.com/eclipse-iceoryx/iceoryx-project-template) and its [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/eclipse-iceoryx/iceoryx-project-template/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt) might be useful. It's a template on how to build and use the upstream iceoryx from source. `find_package` is used together with `FetchContent`. Then you can avoid dealing with include paths.

It's used for the ara::com-like [automotive SOA binding](https://github.com/eclipse-iceoryx/iceoryx-automotive-soa).